# ListActivity onItemClickListener

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I am using List Activity with List View.List activity working perfectly when I click the item going to another activity and display that list name also.My problem is i want to write another list activity in the second activity. when i extend listactivtiy onitemclick listerner is not working. Force to close is coming on the emulator.

How to implement the list activity in the second activity. Means

```
 Intent obj=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Second.class); 
 startActivity(obj);
```

When I extend Second class into ListActivity that time i got force close.I want  to apply the list activity into Second activity class also.

public class Second extends ListActivity
{
}
please help me

Comment: where is this `getAppli()` method?

Comment: try this [link] http://blog.sachinshah.name/?p=62

Comment: first what is getAppli(), second have you added activity in manifeast file, third paste your logcat

Comment: You can't extend `ListView.OnItemClickListener`... It's an interface and you need to implement its required methods.